# Rearranging columns after the sheet is created

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a main worksheet that has all the data and a macro that copies and pastes specific data into a new worksheet. What I need is when the specific data is pasted onto a new worksheet, I need to rearrange the column. Currently it's like this

Country, HYP ID, Cust No, Inv No, Ord No, Ord Type, Prd No, FG/RM, Ship Qty, Sales Ccy, Foreign sales px, Sales $, Total Amount in Foreign Currency

What I want is this:
Country, HYP ID, Cust No, Inv No, Ord No, Ord Type, Prd No, FG/RM, Ship Qty, Sales Ccy, Foreign sales px, Total Amount in Foreign Currency, Sales $

How can I do this?

```
Sub FilterANZ()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim FilterCriteria As String
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim sheetName As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim Found As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim bottomN As Integer
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:AF" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select


   'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
  My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
 My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=AUS", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=NZD"

Set rng1 = Range("f1:g1, j1,l1: n1 , p1: q1 , s1: u1,w1,ag1,y1 ")
Set rng2 = rng1.EntireColumn.Find("*", [f1], , , , xlPrevious)
Set rng1 = Intersect(rng1.EntireColumn, Rows(rng1.Row & ":" & rng2.Row))

Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.Name = "ANZ"
rng1.Copy ws.[a1]
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set btn = ANZ.Buttons.Add(390, 61.5, 94.5, 31.5)

    'Lable button
    btn.Characters.Text = "Reorder"

    'Assign existing macro (Macro1) to button
    btn.OnAction = "reorder"





 End Sub
```

Comment: Have you ever used VBA? If so, you could turn on the 'record macro', do it manually and save the code, then have it executed after your existing macro runs.

Comment: I'm still new to this so, i require some assistance. what i have now is this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can be added to your existing macro to change the column order (all you are doing is switching the last two columns):

```
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Columns("N:N")
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```